# Unable to bind to property of custom component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, binding, components

Can't seem to bind to data from within a custom component. I've tried BindUtilis and {} but can't seem to fathom it out. Here's what I've got:

I have a class DataModel which has been made bindable

Within Mainn.mxml I have two components: DataGrid (used for testing) & CustomComponent (which extends Canvas)

When the data within DataModel.somelist is updated the DataGrid reflects the changes but the CustomComponent doesn't appear to.

I was expecting to see the trace (CustomComponent.dataProvider) fired whenever this._dataModel.itemList is changed. What am I doing wrong?

Main.mxml looks something like this:

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import model.DataModel;

    [Bindable]
    private var _dataModel:DataModel = DataModel.getInstance();

]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
    <views:ItemDisplayList  width="100%" height="300" id="idl" >
        <views:dataProvider>
            {this._dataModel.itemList}
        </views:dataProvider>
    </views:ItemDisplayList>

    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="300" >
        <mx:dataProvider>
            {this._dataModel.itemList}
        </mx:dataProvider>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:VBox>
```

The CustomComponent has this AS class:

```
package code{

import model.DataModel;
import mx.containers.Canvas;

public class CustomComponent extends Canvas{

    [Bindable]
    private var _dataModel:DataModel = DataModel.getInstance();

    private var _dataProvider:ArrayCollection ;  

    public function CustomComponent(){
        super();
        _dataProvider = new ArrayCollection();
        trace("CustomComponent start");
    }

    public function get dataProvider() : ArrayCollection {
        trace("get dataProvider");
        return _dataProvider;
    }

    public function set dataProvider(value: ArrayCollection) : void {
        trace("set dataProvider");
        this._dataProvider = value;
        invalidateProperties();
        invalidateSize();
        invalidateDisplayList();
        dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));
   }

   ...


    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number ) : void{
        trace("updateDisplayList");       
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);         
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you resetting the dataProvider in your custom component, or by updating you mean adding/removing an item from `dataModel.itemList`?

If you're adding an item to `dataModel.itemList`, then your custom component wont update but the DataGrid will.  This is because in the DataGrid (maybe it's in the core ListBase component in Flex?), when you `set dataProvider`, it adds an event listener for `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE`.  When it hears that (when something in your ArrayCollection/IList changes, from remove/add/refresh/etc), it runs a few methods to update the DataGrid's itemRenderers.  You'll have to code that manually if you create your own dataProvider property.

If you set the dataProvider explicitly on your custom component (`custom.dataProvider = myArrayCollection`), it will update.  But that's not the most efficient thing to do.  I recommend extending one of the List classes that has already implemented a dataProvider property, it's a lot to tackle.

Check out the [source for the mx ListBase's dataProvider method](http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/flex/sdk/trunk/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.as) to see what they did.

Hope that helps,
Lance

Comment: Thanks Lance. I had a feeling that somewhere a listener was being added, I guess I was hoping that using Bindable or BindUtils it might be automatic. Anyway, I'll follow your advice here and see where it leads me.